# failing to get output from function

Tags: node.js, xml2js

I'm trying to figure out how to get value from `xml` file and output that value to console.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

const sourceFile = path.join(__dirname, 'books.xml');

const document = (sourceFile, callback) => {
  fs.readFile(sourceFile, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }

    parseString(data, (err, result) => {
      result.catalog.book.forEach(users => {
        callback(users.email);
      });
    });
  });
};

console.log(document(sourceFile, data => data));
```

The xml itself is very simple:

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <email>test@test.com</email>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

But what I am getting from the function is `undefined`. Why does it happen?

Update:
I'm trying to send returned value to nodemailer

```
transporter.sendMail({ from: 'mail@mail.com', to: document(sourceFile, (data) => data), subject: 'Message', text: 'I hope this message gets sent!', }, (err, info) => { if (err) { console.log('error!'); console.log(err.message); } else { console.log('sucess!'); console.log(info.messageId); console.log(info.response); }
```

but I get an error:
'Missing required header 'To'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing value of data, instead printing returned value of `document` function (Which doesn't return anything, thus `undefined`).

I have modified the code, so now it will work as you desired,

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

const sourceFile = path.join(__dirname, 'books.xml');

const document = (sourceFile, callback) => {
  fs.readFile(sourceFile, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }

    parseString(data, (err, result) => {
      result.catalog.book.forEach(users => {
        callback(users.email);
      });
    });
  });
};

document(sourceFile, data => console.log(data));
```

Update: As per OP's comment,

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

const sourceFile = path.join(__dirname, 'books.xml');

const document = (sourceFile, callback) => {
  fs.readFile(sourceFile, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }

    parseString(data, (err, result) => {
      result.catalog.book.forEach(users => {
        callback(users.email);
      });
    });
  });
};

document(sourceFile, data => {
  transporter.sendMail({ from: 'mail@mail.com', to: data, subject: 'Message', text: 'I hope this message gets sent!', }, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error!');
      console.log(err.message);
    } else {
      console.log('sucess!');
      console.log(info.messageId);
      console.log(info.response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to send returned value to nodemailer


`transporter.sendMail({
  from: 'mail@mail.com',
  to: document(sourceFile, (data) => data),
  subject: 'Message',
  text: 'I hope this message gets sent!',
}, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error!');
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('sucess!');
    console.log(info.messageId);
    console.log(info.response);
  }
`

but this is the error I'm geting intead:
'Missing required header 'To'.'

Comment: @KarolisArbačiauskas, please add an update to the question for same, will update my answer. So question answer stay in sync.

Comment: @KarolisArbačiauskas I have added update patch to answer.

Comment: Thank you! working like a charm. Could you explain, please, why do I need to move sendmail function to callback?

Comment: You have to understand the working of `callbacks`, `async` and similar stuff. You were doing several mistakes. First, you were calling a function in a manner that it will return value, but the value is coming with callback as it;s async operation. Second, You were not waiting for the callback to fire to further execution.

Comment: Read this article, https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/